# Set cookies from multiple get

Tags: php

I need to set more variables (and get more values) from one get.

Example:

```
// Example page: shoppingcart.php?size=S,XL

$size=$_GET['size'];

SetCookie("size", $size, Time() + 7*24*60*60);
```

After setting these cookies I need to transfer to billing.php where I need to write these cookies to the same mysql query (same query for 2 and more products).

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I need to have two or more "values" for the GET size (in url).
And from these values set cookies (like $_COOKIE['size'][0], $_COOKIE['size'][1] etc..)

Comment: Do you mean the url than would be adjusted to e.g. ..?size=S,XL&size2=M,L (just as an example) or do you want to keep the url like it is and split S and XL as separate values for size0 and size1?

Comment: Yes, I want to split as you wrote. Separate size S with value size0 etc..)

Comment: @user2808698 then [split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php) or [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) it

Answer (score 0):

It would work like this - you split the value you get using php explode:

```
var $sizes_array = explode(',', $size);
```

Then you e.g. combine the values as string to set as value for the cookie:

```
var $cookie_value = "size0=" . $sizes_array[0] . "&size1=" . $sizes_array[1];
```

and set it as cookie value

```
SetCookie("size", $cookie_value, Time() + 7*24*60*60);
```

A cookie only has one value but the maximum length of this value is sufficient for your request (just read an article stating it'd be about 4000 characters but don't take this as valid information because this browsercheck doesn't cover all browsers).
When you retrieve the cookie value for further processing, you should be able to get the values of size0=S&size1=L back with php.